# the shop page and product page are showing incorrectly in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I an using a custom theme.Recently I added woocommerce to it.

**set up**

I've added theme support to function.php .

I copied the template folder to my theme folder and rename it to woocommerce.

I made woocommerce.php in my theme folder.

**The problem:**

The shop and product page are showing incorrectly.In shop page it shows one product per row instead of 4 products!

I disabled other plugins and css files and didn't work, But when I changed the theme to storefront theme it looked fine.

Can you help me with settings and updates

Thank you in advance for your feedback

[My Shop page](http://www.hrkhedmatgozar.ir/shop/)

[My Product page](http://www.hrkhedmatgozar.ir/product/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D9%84%DB%8C-iso100152019-%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%B4%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%DA%AF/)

Comment: When asking for help troubleshooting an issue with a website, please don't simply paste a link to the website into the question. Instead, include a [mre] of the issue within the question itself. Posts containing only a link to another website and no code in the question are likely to be closed for not having enough details.  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) for why this is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam Elham,
I see you install WooCommerce and add them, there is a problem in archive page,
you use the following structure, which is not correct:

```
<ul class="products columns-5 row">
<section class="col-lg-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
<li class="and-other-classes">
</li>
</section>
</ul>
```

The problem is related to your CSS and styles, Change it as bellow:

```
<ul class="products columns-5 row">
<section class="row">
<li class="col-lg-6 col-lg-3 text-center and-other-classes">
</li>
</section>
</ul>
```